# Broadcast a byte value to all 16 XMM slots in Delphi ASM

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-7, sse, basm

This is easy in AVX with the VBROADCASTS command, or in SSE if the value were doubles or floats.

How do I broadcast a single 8-bit value to every slot in an XMM register in Delphi ASM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean you have a byte in the LSB of an XMM register and want to duplicate it across all lanes of that register? I don't know Delphi's inline assembly syntax, but in Intel/MASM syntax it could be done something like this:

```
punpcklbw xmm0,xmm0    ; xxxxxxxxABCDEFGH -> xxxxxxxxEEFFGGHH
punpcklwd xmm0,xmm0    ; xxxxxxxxEEFFGGHH -> xxxxxxxxGGGGHHHH
punpckldq xmm0,xmm0    ; xxxxxxxxGGGGHHHH -> xxxxxxxxHHHHHHHH
punpcklqdq xmm0,xmm0   ; xxxxxxxxHHHHHHHH -> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. How do I load the initial byte into the LSB? The references I've found are again oriented to floats.

Comment: The `MOVD` instruction lets you move the contents of a 32-bit register or memory location into an `xmm` register.

Comment: I'm assuming the last instruction should read "punpcklqdq" :)

Comment: You can `pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0` once you get to dword elements.  Or better: `punpcklbw` / `pshuflw` / `punpcklqdq` (faster on Merom / K8 and earlier when `pshufd` and other 128b shuffles with granularity less than 64-bit are slower).

Answer (score 5):

Michael's answer will work. As an alternative, if you can assume the `SSSE3` instruction set, then using **Packed Shuffle Bytes** [`pshufb`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFB.html) would also work.

Assuming (1) an 8-bit value in `AL` (for example) and (2) the desired broadcast destination to be `XMM1`, and (3) that another register, say `XMM0`, is available, this will do the trick:

```
movd   xmm1, eax  ;// move value in AL (part of EAX) into XMM1
pxor   xmm0, xmm0 ;// clear xmm0 to create the appropriate mask for pshufb
pshufb xmm1, xmm0 ;// broadcast lowest value into all slots of xmm1
```

And yes, Delphi's BASM understands SSSE3.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest option is SSSE3 for `pshufb` if it's available.

```
; SSSE3
pshufb      xmm0,  xmm1       ; where xmm1 is zeroed, e.g. with pxor xmm1,xmm1
```

Otherwise you should usually use this:

```
; SSE2 only
punpcklbw   xmm0, xmm0        ; xxxxxxxxABCDEFGH -> xxxxxxxxEEFFGGHH
pshuflw     xmm0, xmm0, 0     ; xxxxxxxxEEFFGGHH -> xxxxxxxxHHHHHHHH
punpcklqdq  xmm0, xmm0        ; xxxxxxxxHHHHHHHH -> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

This is better than punpckl  bw / wd -> `pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0` because there are [some CPUs with only 64-bit shuffle units.  (Including Merom and K8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86).  On such CPUs, `pshuflw` is fast, and so is `punpcklqdq`, but `pshufd` and `punpck` with granularity less than 64-bit is slow.  So this sequence uses only one "slow shuffle" instruction, vs. 3 for bw / wd / pshufd.

On all later CPUs, there's no difference between those two 3-instruction sequence, so it doesn't cost us anything to tune for old CPUs in this case.  See also http://agner.org/optimize/ for instruction tables.

This is the sequence from Michael's answer with the middle two instructions replaced by `pshuflw`.

---

If your byte is in an integer register to start with, you can use a multiply by `0x01010101` to broadcast it to 4 bytes.  e.g.

```
; movzx   eax, whatever

imul   edx, eax, 0x01010101    ; edx = al repeated 4 times

movd   xmm0, eax
pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0
```

Note that `imul`'s non-immediate source operand can be memory, but it has to be a 32-bit memory location with your byte zero-extended to 32 bits.

---

If your data starts in memory, loading into an integer register first is probably not worth it.  Just `movd` to an xmm register.  (Or possibly `pinsrb` if you need to avoid a wider load to avoid crossing a page or maybe a cache line.  But that has a false dependency on the old value of the register where `movd` doesn't.)

If instruction throughput is more of an issue than latency, it can be worth considering `pmuludq` if you can't use `pshufb`, even though it has 5 cycle latency on most CPUs.

```
; low 32 bits of xmm0 = your byte, **zero extended**
pmuludq xmm0, xmm7        ; xmm7 = 0x01010101 in the low 32 bits
pshufd  xmm0, xmm0, 0
```

Comment: Wow, you sure know your SSE. One question: how would pinsrb every cross a page?

Comment: @IamIC: It wouldn't, that's why you'd use it *instead of* `movd` to get a byte into the low byte of an xmm registers.

Comment: *"... multiply by 0x01010101 to broadcast it..."* - that's clever.